# why Postman and mongoDb db.getCollectionNames return empty array?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest, api, postman

I have a spring boot application connecting to a local mongoDB database. When I try to fetch all records from a collection it returns an empty array.

**Facture.class**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "Facture")
public class Facture {

    @Id
    private Long id_facture;
    private int num_facture;
    private double prix;
    private String methode_paiement;
```

**FactureRepository**

```
import com.app.Model.Facture;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FactureDao extends MongoRepository<Facture, Long> {
}
```

**Postman results**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-25T00:56:13.597+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/all"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is should change id type to String and thats it works